# Balanced Incomplete Block Design, times a pair of varieties are compared = λ and variety.

Tags: abstract-algebra, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am struggling to understand what is meant by:

- "times a pair of varieties are compared = λ"
- "subsets containing anyone variety = r"

What is meant by these statements in relation to a BIBD design?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design)

$r$ is the number of sets containing a point $x$ and this has to be independent of the choice of $x$.

$\lambda$ is the number of sets containing the pair $(x,y)$ and this has to be independent of the choice of $x$ and $y$.

Example is from me : Suppose $X$ is a list of hockey teams. Then $k$ is $2$, the number of teams in a game. $r$ the number of games played by each team and $\lambda$ is the number of times each pair of teams meet.

Comment: what is meant by "independent of the choice of x & y" in both λ and r?

Comment: A team should not play more than the others. And teams should meet each other the same amount of time. (Note that this is not the case in the NHL for example).